# Linking Comboboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a pair of combobox in a form called ,"Cover". The first combobox contains years as its data e.g. 2011, 2012, etc. The second combobox contains all the names of hotels. 
I have another form called, Form_1, this has the same pair of comboboxes.

Consider the below scanrio:
A user selects two values from the comboboxes present in the first form "COVER" and then clicks on FORM_1 to proceed further. When the user opens Form_1 the comboboxes should already have the values chosen from "COVER".

This is what I have tried in VBA but was returned with an error "Cannot assign Value":

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Combo5.Value = Form_0_Cover.Combo0.Value
Combo7.Value = Form_0_Cover.Combo2.Value
End Sub
```

I want Form_1 to store the values the user chose from COVER automatically when the user clicks Form_1 to open. So the user does not need to choose those values again.

Thanks for help.
Sorry if I have confused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the Open event to assign values to controls as they have not yet been created. Use the Load event. Then:

```
Combo5 = Forms!Form_0_Cover.Combo0
```